# Gazebo 1.9 failed to load plugin: libgazebo_ros_camera.so

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using Gazebo 1.9 with ROS groovy. As I am trying the RRBot example([Link here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins#Running_the_RRBot_Example)), I kept getting the following error messages when launching gazebo:

---

Error [Plugin.hh:127] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_camera.so: libCameraPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error [Plugin.hh:127] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so: libGpuRayPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

---

I am using gazebo_ ros_ pkg within catkin workspace, and the ".so" files are actually located in /home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib. 
 Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4545/gazebo-1.9-failed-to-load-plugin:-libgazebo_ros_camera.so/) by [Mark_GU](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/506/mark_gu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-10-01**:
Hello,

I'm working in RRbot but I have problems with the catkin_make in this Tutorial

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo

the problem is when to used:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos.git
cd ..
catkin_make
```

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-10-01**:\

Get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/catkinmake", line 14, in <module> from catkin.terminalcolor import     disableANSIcolors, fmt
ImportError:
```

**Comment by [Mark_GU](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/506/mark_gu/) on 2013-10-01**:
@vncntmh  Not quite familiar with your problem, it looks like something went wrong with your catkin workspace. Does "catkin_make" work before your included the package "gazebo_ ros_ demos"?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-10-01**:
@Mark_GU, the problem were because I had used ros/fuerte and it change to ros/groovy

A lot of thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

what is in your `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` variable (type `echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` in a terminal)

if it not contains `/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel` you should append it (type `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH:/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel`)

I haven't found this in the tutorial but I think it must be there somewhere ;)

you can find it in the manual [Manual plugins](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__components__plugins.html)

hope this solves your problem

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark_GU](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/506/mark_gu/) on 2013-10-01**:
Thank you. I tried the method your suggested. Somehow my GAZEBO_ PLUGIN_ PATH shows nothing by default. So now even if I added "/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel" to it, I still get the error. Thus I was wondering if any other path is needed

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Check this post:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4535/error-pluginhh127/

Goodbye!!

---

Originally posted by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) with karma: 80 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark_GU](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/506/mark_gu/) on 2013-10-01**:
Can you please show me all the paths included in your GAZEBO_ PLUGIN_ PATH? Because my GAZEBO_ PLUGIN_ PATH defaults to nothing. Even when I added the path that includes the .so file, it is still showing the error. Thanks

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2013-10-01**:
Okay,

My path is libmyplugin.so and this's In ~/gazebo/my_plugin/build

Before to get this path I used:

```
cmake ..;make  //in the folder /build
```

I used:

```
cd ~/gazebo/my_plugin/build  //here is libmyplugin.so

export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH  //with this instruction I load libmyplugin.so and it's prepared it for load the simulation
gazebo
```

In my case I insert the robot from Gazebo

hope this solves your problem, GoodBye!!